# How to check if ModuleController has selected Controller before the test runs?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have tests (JMX) with modular controllers and sometimes throw an error when they are started when there are modular controllers without a controller selected.

Is there a way to verify if every (enabled) modular controller has an associated controller?

Answer (score 2):

As of JMeter 5.4.1 it is not possible to "validate" the Module Controllers without actually running your tests, the [Test Plan Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html) is being built in the runtime from the test elements provided and controllers like [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) or [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) basically modify the Test Plan Tree on the fly creating one big test plan from reusable fragments or external scripts.

So the options are in:

1. Perform a [dry-run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_run_(testing)) with 1-2 users/iterations to see whether your test still works, produces .jtl file without errors, etc.
2. It's also possible to [run JMeter from Java code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) so you could come up with an utility which will do the test plan checking basing on your acceptance criteria

Comment: **Option 1:** I have this option in my sanity test [Sample code](https://git.io/J0JbD)  **Option 2 :** `RUN A JMETER TEST THROUGH A PROGRAM (FROM JAVA CODE)` will be useful to create a utility as you suggest. Let me give it a try.

Comment: I tried the Java option. I am getting an error as plugs are not mapped in the Java code. How to map the plugins from Java code? I am using Random CSV, Concurrency  Thread Group, and Throughput Shaping Timer in the JMX.

Comment: You need to have all the plugins in your project classpath